# Is there a way to get the IP address that assigned to the new STA that connected to ESP32 along with its MAC address?

Tags: esp32

I want to get the IP address that just assigned by the DHCP to the new STA that just connected to the ESP32 along with its MAC address.

i was thinking about using the "dhcp_search_ip_on_mac()" function passing to it the parameter "&event->event_info.sta_connected.mac" but the problem is the "SYSTEM_EVENT_AP_STAIPASSIGNED" event id has no event data struction and the sta_connected.mac variable is from the "SYSTEM_EVENT_AP_STACONNECTED" event id. but i was thinking what if i face a multi connections at the same time, what if at the moment the ESP uses sta_connected.mac to get the ip address from DHCP search function, that variable will have the mac address of another STA and not of the one that triggered the event id  "SYSTEM_EVENT_AP_STACONNECTED".

```
esp_err_t eventHandler(void *ctx, system_event_t *event){
 switch (event->event_id)
 {
   case SYSTEM_EVENT_AP_STACONNECTED:
    printf("STA just connected.\n");
    printf("STA MAC@: %s\n", ip4addr_ntoa(&event->event_info.sta_connected.mac));
    break;
   case SYSTEM_EVENT_AP_STAIPASSIGNED:
    ip4_addr_t staAddr;
    dhcp_search_ip_on_mac(&event->event_info.sta_connected.mac, &staAddr);
    printf("STA ip address maybe %s\n", ip4addr_ntoa(&staAddr));
    break;
   default:
    break;
 }
 return ESP_OK;
}
```

Comment: According to the documentation there should be a `struct ip_event_ap_staipassigned_t` which is the even structure of IP_EVENT_AP_STAIPASSIGNED with `ip4_addr_t ip` as a member. Did you gave it a try?

Comment: but how can i call it? because i have only those variable in my event_info:
ap_probereqrecved, got_ip, auth_change, connected, disconnected, got_ip6, scan_done, sta_connected, sta_disconnected, sta_er_fail_reason, sta_er_pin. sorry i had to write them all. but as you can see, i have no variable have the word "staipassigned". :/

Comment: the documentation said. SYSTEM_EVENT_AP_STAIPASSIGNED event id has no data struction. Check the table "Event IDs and Corresponding Data Structures" in this link https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-guides/event-handling.html?highlight=SYSTEM_EVENT_AP_STAIPASSIGNED

Comment: Same documentation: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-reference/network/tcpip_adapter.html?highlight=IP_EVENT_AP_STAIPASSIGNED#_CPPv427ip_event_ap_staipassigned_t So question is who is right? The doc or the doc? Did you test it already?

Comment: https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/3bb7dba9957ee71a236058322ae5e70f96f9a104/components/tcpip_adapter/tcpip_adapter_lwip.c looking at ll 91 I am pretty sure that you will get the IP as well.

Comment: it's confusing. in one hand they give you the struction type and in other hand they tell you they are no such data. i found this one i git and now i'm more sure that they are a way to get that ip. https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/pull/2440/commits/0fd93a5117ef851891b71283c3dc42d34f2b9c99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the fact that following code can be found in [tcpip_adapter/tcpip_adapter_lwip.c](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/3bb7dba9957ee71a236058322ae5e70f96f9a104/components/tcpip_adapter/tcpip_adapter_lwip.c)

```
static void tcpip_adapter_dhcps_cb(u8_t client_ip[4])
{
    ESP_LOGI(TAG,"softAP assign IP to station,IP is: %d.%d.%d.%d",
                client_ip[0],client_ip[1],client_ip[2],client_ip[3]);
    system_event_t evt;
    memset(&evt, 0, sizeof(system_event_t));
    evt.event_id = SYSTEM_EVENT_AP_STAIPASSIGNED;
    memcpy((char *)&evt.event_info.ap_staipassigned.ip.addr, (char *)client_ip, sizeof(evt.event_info.ap_staipassigned.ip.addr));
    esp_event_send(&evt);
}
```

I would assume that handling IP_EVENT_AP_STAIPASSIGNED / SYSTEM_EVENT_AP_STAIPASSIGNED
 and reading event->event_info.ap_staipassigned.ip.addr should work in your case.

EDIT:
the following compiles just fine for me. But one need the lastest version of the esp-idf as this functionality seems to be added recently.

```
case IP_EVENT_AP_STAIPASSIGNED:
    {
        int addr = event->event_info.ap_staipassigned.ip.addr;
        ESP_LOGI(TAG0, "%d",addr);
    }break;
```

tested with version master 6fd535c .

Comment: first of all thank you for helping me, but as i said, i don't have such thing ap_staipassigned under event->event_info.
and i tried to create another event handler using esp_event_handler_register and not the event_loop. i will post the code in new comment hopefully to be clear.

Comment: static void wifiEventHandler(void* arg, esp_event_base_t event_base, int32_t event_id, void*even_data){
    if(event_id == SYSTEM_EVENT_AP_STAIPASSIGNED || event_id == IP_EVENT_AP_STAIPASSIGNED){
       ip4_addr_t ipAddr = (ip_event_ap_staipassigned_t*) event_data->ip;
       printf("the assigned IP@ is %s\n", ip4addr_ntoa(&ipAddr));
    }
}

and i call it like this:
ESP_ERROR_CHECK(esp_event_handler_register(ESP_EVENT_ANY_BASE , ESP_EVENT_ANY_ID, &wifiEventHandler, NULL));

Comment: but building the project lead to multi errors because he can't find IP_EVENT_AP_STAIPASSIGNED and ip_event_ap_staipassigned_t. no such variable, both of them are undeclared or undefined. if the code wasn't clear i can edit my post and add it.

Comment: Which version of ESP-IDF do you use? I had to update mine but now it is compling fine. Version 6fd535c  SHA-1: 6fd535c985f0019ffe8a924e62a57e29a9007a28

Comment: i'm using platformio. the platforms library shows 3.30200.190418 (3.2.0). so it's 3.2.0, not the latest version. i guess platformio uses the stable version only.

Comment: hm you could try to update the esp-idf of your platformio manually. In the community platform of plaformio is a way mentioned: _Clone (or download) the esp-idf repo then copy the folders: components, make and tools to
C:\Users\[your user]\.platformio\packages\framework-espidf_

Comment: alternatively you could try to hack in this functionality by copying the passages from tcpip_adapter_lwip.c into your version or you just wait until platformio is updated.

Comment: thank you for your help. and about updating by replacing the repo may cause a problem. so it doesn't worth it. i'm only trying to learn about esp32 and freeRTOS. if i really need it. i would go for building the new version instead of replacing files. even doing some hack is more convenient then that XD. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue for the ESP8266_RTOS_SDK, I downloaded recently.
Went to the **tcpip_adapter_lwip.c** and just added ip to the **event_info.got_ip.ip_info.ip.addr** field:

```
static void tcpip_adapter_dhcps_cb(u8_t client_ip[4])
{
    ESP_LOGI(TAG,"softAP assign IP to station,IP is: %d.%d.%d.%d", client_ip[0],client_ip[1],client_ip[2],client_ip[3]);
    system_event_t evt;
    evt.event_id = SYSTEM_EVENT_AP_STAIPASSIGNED;
    evt.event_info.got_ip.ip_info.ip.addr = (client_ip[3] << 24) | (client_ip[2] << 16) | (client_ip[1] << 8) | client_ip[0];
    esp_event_send(&evt);
}
```